# What causes "InvalidKey"?

Tags: might-and-magic-heroes-6, drm

I bought the game, installed it and the Ubisoft launcher asked for my serial key. I entered it, and it accepted it.

I then opened the game and I could start a game, etc. But trying many other things like multiplayer etc would popup an error trying to connect to CONFLUX saying "Connection failed! InvalidKey", screenshot:

[image]

What causes this and how can I fix it (or contact Ubisoft)? It accepted the key during setup.

Comment: Have you tried contacting Ubisoft?

Comment: What would be the proper way to contact them? Not sure how.

Comment: You aren't the only one as this seems to be an issue at Ubisoft.  See my answer below.

Comment: Did you preorder the game?

Comment: or did you purchase the russian version of this?

Comment: I didn't preorder it. How do I tell if my version is Russian? It should be English...

Comment: From what I have found, the preodered versions had their keys voided for some reason and same with the Russian retail version.  It seems like the developers had a few issues with their activation.  But I would contact Ubisoft about this, as they handled the key distribution.  See Answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seeing as Ubisoft handled the key distribution, I would contact them here.  I do not have (nor do I want) your login information at Ubisoft, so I will have to send you to their  [generic support page.](http://ubisoft.custhelp.com/app/answers/list/p/88)

Once you are there, click 'Ask a Question' above.  This is will now prompt you to enter in your Ubisoft credentials.

Last, you have to select the platform and game you are playing on.  If you cannot find your exact game - just find and select the closest result - Their support staff will properly adjust the ticket.  Their turn around time is roughly 24-72 hours on average (at least for myself).